# SYSRET vs SYSRETQ distinction and compatibility mode

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture

I'm going with the Intel implementation of the SYSCALL/SYSRET instructions. If I'm reading [their documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) correctly, unlike [AMD's implmenetation](https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf) of SYSCALL, Intel's version can be called only from a 64-bit long mode. Is that correct?

But then if I read Intel's documentation for the accompanying instruction SYSRET, it comes in two flavors:

- SYSRET `0F 07` = "Return to compatibility mode from fast system call"
- SYSRETQ `48 0F 07` = "Return to 64-bit mode from fast system call"

So I'm just trying to understand it, at which point will `SYSRET` (`0F 07`) be used to return to compatibility mode if `SYSCALL` cannot be called from it?

Comment: Compatibility mode is a subset of 64-bit long mode.

Comment: @RossRidge: Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 4):

While Intel's version of SYSCALL can't be used in compatibility mode, the SYSRET instruction can be used from 64-bit mode to "return" to compatibility mode. The SYSRET instruction doesn't require a previous SYSCALL instruction to work, jut like the RET instruction doesn't require a previous CALL instruction.

The Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual documents the operation of the SYSRET instruction as follows:

> IF (CS.L ≠ 1 ) or (IA32_EFER.LMA ≠ 1) or (IA32_EFER.SCE ≠ 1) (* Not in
>   64-Bit Mode or SYSCALL/SYSRET not enabled in IA32_EFER *)
>       THEN #UD; FI;
>   IF (CPL ≠ 0) OR (RCX is not canonical) THEN #GP(0); FI;
>   IF (operand size is 64-bit)
>       THEN (* Return to 64-Bit Mode *)
>           RIP ← RCX;
>       ELSE (* Return to Compatibility Mode *)
>           RIP ← ECX;
>   FI;
>   RFLAGS ← (R11 & 3C7FD7H) | 2; (* Clear RF, VM, reserved bits; set bit 2 *)
>
> IF (operand size is 64-bit)
>       THEN CS.Selector ← IA32_STAR[63:48]+16;
>       ELSE CS.Selector ← IA32_STAR[63:48];
>   FI;
>   CS.Selector ← CS.Selector OR 3; (* RPL forced to 3 *)
>   (* Set rest of CS to a fixed value *)
>   CS.Base> ← 0; (* Flat segment *)
>   CS.Limit ← FFFFFH; (* With 4-KByte granularity, implies a 4-GByte limit *)
>   CS.Type ← 11; (* Execute/read code, accessed *)
>   CS.S ← 1;
>   CS.DPL ← 3;
>   CS.P ← 1;
>   IF (operand size is> 64-bit)
>       THEN (* Return to 64-Bit Mode *)
>           CS.L ← 1; (* 64-bit code segment *)
>           CS.D ← 0; (* Required if CS.L = 1 *)
>       ELSE (* Return to Compatibility Mode *)
>           CS.L ← 0; (* Compatibility mode *)
>           CS.D ← 1; (* 32-bit code segment *)
>   FI;
>   CS.G ← 1; (* 4-KByte granularity *)
>   CPL ← 3;
>   [...]

As you can see there are differences between the operation depending on the operand size. Notably with a 32-bit operand size the the CS.L and CS.D flags set to 0 and 1 meaning the CPU begins executing instructions at the address given by ECX in 32-bit compatibility mode. It does this regardless how the kernel (privilege level 0) was entered.

While on Intel CPUs the 32-bit operand size version of SYSRET can't be used in the way that would be the most obvious, to resume execution of a 32-bit compatibility mode task that used SYSCALL to enter the kernel, it could still have other uses. Like starting the execution of a new 32-bit task or maybe even resuming one that entered the kernel by some other means.

Comment: Btw, how does a 32-bit user-mode code enter 64-bit kernel mode? (Let's take Windows for this example.) I'm assuming via a far call to an inter-privilege call-gate, right. I guess in that case, the kernel routine can adjust the stack and use `sysret`. Although this whole "adjusting" code may totally negate the efficiency gained by using `sysret` vs just using the plain old `retf`. Anyway, I need to re into Wow64 on Windows to see what they're doing there. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeF Either through an interrupt (software or hardware), exception, far call/jmp through a gate, or SYSENTER instruction. Windows uses SYSENTER for system calls, and doesn't use far call/jmp through gates for anything as far as I know.

Comment: @MikeF 64-bit Windows processes use `syscall` to enter the kernel and 32-bit processes on 64-bit Windows (WoW64) first perform a far call in user mode to a 64-bit code segment and then `syscall` is used. So the return to compat mode capability of `sysret` is not used on Windows; it always returns to 64-bit mode.

Comment: I think Linux too does not use `sysret` to return to compat mode. This could be because it's slower than other methods (like you suggested). But then why would Intel support `sysret` to return to compat mode if `syscall` cannot be used in compat mode. This only makes sense to me if it is faster than other methods, which I doubt.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Yeah, I thought too that Windows uses `syscall` for the kernel mode calls. So going back to my original question, it sounds weird to support `sysret` into compatibility mode when `syscall` from it is not supported. (I know that AMD implementation of `syscall` supports it both ways, so there it will be more logical to have that implementation of `sysret`.)

Comment: @HadiBrais Linux has the `__kernel_vsyscall` function in vdso.so which can use INT $0x80, SYSCALL or SYSENTER depending on the capabilities of the CPU. (Though in practice 32-bit software may just use INT $0x80 directly.)

Comment: @HadiBrais: 32-bit Linux system calls are normally made with `sysenter`.  The kernel side of it is in [`entry_64_compat.S`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S), along with other entry points into a 64-bit kernel from 32-bit userspace (see also [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) for more about `int 0x80`).   The user-space side of the `sysenter` save/restore dance done by code in the VDSO page the kernel maps into every process, called by glibc

Comment: Congratulations for your new badge!